# Tkinter Entry widget is returning an empty list when used in a toplevel window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

I am attempting to open a new window when the New Window button is pressed in the main "root" window. This currently works and does indeed open a second window. In the second window I want to ask the user for an input and then this input will be turned into a list of strings.

An example input would be `"Amy, Bob, Carl"`. The expected output would be `['Amy', 'Bob', 'Carl']` but currently the program just returns `['']`.

My current code is:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Welcome screen")
root.geometry("300x300")

def open_new_window():

    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("second window")

    entities = Entry(top)
    entries = entities.get().split(", ")
    entities.pack()
    entities.focus_set()
    print(entries)

    sub_button = Button(top, text="Submit", command= ?)
    sub_button.pack(pady=20)
    close_btn = Button(top, text="Close", command=top.destroy)
    close_btn.pack()

open_button = Button(root, text="New Window", command=open_new_window)
open_button.pack(pady=20)
exit_button = Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

I am new to Tkinter and I am unsure why this is happening. I'm sure it's a simple silly mistake but I can't find where I am going wrong. I also am unsure as to whether I need a **Submit** button as I don't know what command should be passed to it.

Any advice is appreciated. Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we will understand why you got a empty list: your code is executed sequentially, so when you do the `entities.get()` you haven't yet written anything nor pressed "Submit", i.e., you want to read the entry box once you press the "Submit", not earlier, for that reason, you have the `command = ?`.
As I am aware, you have mainly 2 options:

1. Get the text from the button itself
2. Create a variable linked to the entry box and read this

### Method 1: read the data from the entry

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Welcome screen")
root.geometry("300x300")

def do_stuff(entry):
    print(entry.get())

def open_new_window():

    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("second window")

    entities = Entry(top)
    entities.pack()
    entities.focus_set()

    sub_button = Button(top, text="Submit", command= lambda: do_stuff(entities))
    sub_button.pack(pady=20)
    close_btn = Button(top, text="Close", command=top.destroy)
    close_btn.pack()

open_button = Button(root, text="New Window", command=open_new_window)
open_button.pack(pady=20)
exit_button = Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

### Method 2: link a variable

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Welcome screen")
root.geometry("300x300")

def do_stuff(text_entry):
        print(text_entry.get())

def open_new_window():

    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("second window")

    text_entry = StringVar()
    entities = Entry(top, textvariable = text_entry)
    entities.pack()
    entities.focus_set()

    sub_button = Button(top, text="Submit", command= lambda: do_stuff(text_entry))
    sub_button.pack(pady=20)
    close_btn = Button(top, text="Close", command=top.destroy)
    close_btn.pack()

open_button = Button(root, text="New Window", command=open_new_window)
open_button.pack(pady=20)
exit_button = Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

The main advantage in this last approach is that you can play with the text before and after the entry is built.

Comment: thank you, that worked perfectly! What does ```lambda``` do when used in ```command= lambda: do_stuff(entities)``` or ```command= lambda: do_stuff(text_entry)```?

Comment: `command` expects a function to call, for example in `open_button = Button(root, text="New Window", command=open_new_window)`, `open_new_window` is a function that will call when the event happens. The problem is that we want to call the function with an argument (`do_stuff(text_entry)` or `do_stuff(entities)`), however, if we use it like that: we have already called the function! `lambda` allows us to create a "anonymous function", it is like creating a function `def call_do_stuff(): do_stuff(text_entry)`, but without the need of creating the function itself